# asp net VNext and older visual studio versions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-core

I am trying to convert my current asp net application to an ASP.Net vnext application and I am trying to figure out if we have have to use Visual Studio 15 or visual studio 14 ctp 3 for vnext to work? Will it work in visual studio 12 or 13?

I found this link 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/18/try-out-the-new-releases-net-framework-vnext-asp-net-vnext-net-native-and-ryujit.aspx

and I haven't heard any updates.

Comment: It states in the article you linked that it's only supported in Visual Studio 14 CTP3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Visual Studio, you *need* Visual Studio 2015 and CTP6.

Good news is, you can have VS2015 installed side by side with 2012 or 2013 with no problems. (really!) And if you are not yet familiarized with the command line tools, I do highly recommend to install vs2015.

For migrations, there's some documentation in the workings on the Docs repo.
check this out : https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/docs/migrating/migratingfrommvc5/migratingfrommvc5.rst

this is just one, there are a few more doc pages on that repo that might help you to get started and see which changes should be made and how to apply one by one.

Unfortunately the documentation is not finished and there's not much about it, so be prepared to have patience because you will be migrating and learning a new stack in the process.

Microsoft team has been very active and helpful in all channels (twitter, SO, github, etc) so, you can at least get help if you find a block.

Answer (score 0):

The tooling for ASP.NET 5 is only available for VS 2015.

However, you can build and run ASP.NET 5 applications outside of VS using the command line tool and other editors.